# Proguard obfuscation of multi jar project

Tags: java, proguard

I have successfully configured Proguard with Maven to obfuscate a jar, and its dependant jar. I have managed to get both obfuscations to use the same mapping file, so that one jar can call the methods of the other. The problem I am facing, is that Proguard is not keeping unique names across the obfuscated jars; both obfuscated jars contain a class called

```
f.b.class
```

As there are two classes called f.b.class (one in each jar), priority is being given to the class inside the calling jar, which is causing problems.

Has anybody experienced this before and are you aware of a solution for this. Currently I am using the

```
-keeppackagenames
```

switch to ensure that the package hierarchy remain different so that any duplicated class names do not conflict. Ideally I would like to remove all package names

The switch

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```

has also been applied but it clearly only applies this to the jar currently being obfuscated. It does don't look and previously obfuscated jars to ensure uniqueness across jars.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I ended up using the -keeppackagenames option. It is not a solution, but a work around.

Comment: Even i have multiple jars in my project and its a sprint project.Due to duplicate classes with same name Eg a, b etc, there is duplicacy of bean names which is affecting the sprint container to come up. to avoid this i have used    -keepnames class package1 -keepnames class package2.. In this way class names are not obfuscated. Is there any better solution than this?